# pointers to functions in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

It's kinda hard to name a title for my question, so plz pardon me for this ambiguous title.

Function names are regarded as the addresses of functions, so we can assign them to function pointers.

```
...
void fun(){cout<<"fun called";}  
int main()
{
typedef void (*pf)();
pf p1 = fun;
//Then we can call p1()
p1();
...
}
```

This is of no problem. What puzzles me is that `pf p2 = &fun; p2();` will do the exact same thing as p1 with no warnings or errors.

"fun" is the address of the function, so shouldn't &fun be **the address of the address** of the function? And when I assign &fun to p2, there should be a type inconsistency, I think.
Why `pf p2 = &fun` is a legal assignment?

Comment: Fun fact: `(*p1)(); (***p1)(); (*****p1)();`

Comment: @KerrekSB - c'mon man, that's just cruel....

Comment: @KerrekSB Why is this? Does the compiler simplily ignore them?

Comment: @richard.g No, that's because `*p1` evaluates to a value of function type, which then immediately decays to a pointer-to-function. If you now dereference it to obtain a function, then this process will repeat, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Function names are regarded as the addresses of functions
>
> "fun" is the address of the function

Neither of these statements is correct. A function name is **not** a pointer but a function designator; it is only the case that it is - similarly to an array - **implicitly converted to a pointer** ("decays into a pointer") in some, but not all, contexts, for example, when assigned to an object of type pointer-to-function or when called.

This implicit conversion does **not** happen when the function is the argument of the unary `&` (address-of) operator, hence `&function_name` will be of type "pointer to function", and not "pointer-to-pointer-to-function".

Answer (score 6):

No.

The id-expression formed by the name of a function *decays* to the function pointer, *except* in certain circumstances. One of those circumstances is when it is the operand of the address-of operator. In that case it does not decay, and the result of evaluating the address-of operator on the function name is the address of the function.